# probability of isoceles and right angle triangle in a cube

Tags: probability

> Three distinct vertices randomly selected among the vertices of a cube. Then the probability that these vertices form an
>
> $(1)$ Equilateral triangle $(2)$ Right angle triangle $(3)$ Isosceles Triangle.

Try: WE have total $8$ vertices. Then total number of ways is $\displaystyle \binom{8}{3}$

and number of equilateral triangle is $8$

So for $(1)$ part , probability is $\displaystyle \frac{8}{\binom{8}{3}}$

But could not understand how can i find number of Right angle triangle and isosceles triangle.

could some help me to solve it , Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: This seems to be a problem of counting.

Split all $\binom 83=56$ possible triangles in three disjoint subsets:

a) all vertices are on the same face of the cube: $ 4\times 6=24$.

b) two vertices are on the same edge, and the other vertex is on the opposite edge of the cube: $2\times 12=24$.

c) the segments connecting the vertices are the face diagonals of the cube $1\times 8=8.$

Observe that all triangles belonging to the same subset are congruent.

Can you take it from here?